# Get values of Tensorflow model.predict without using tf.session()

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, tensorflow-estimator

So I have a prediction network written with tensorflow's new estimator API

I'm calling the prediction like so:

```
prediction = classifier_mycolumn.predict(cust_train_fn)
```

where `classifier_mycolumn` is defined as:

```
classifier_mycolumn = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn = model_function,
        params = {'feature_columns': my_feature_columns,
        'n_classes': 1,},
        model_dir=current_model)
```

just a standard tf.estimator.Estimator thing.

`cust_train_fn` isn't actually a function, it's a single array that the network should take in and run inference on.

The network is supposed to return 0 or 1 (simple classification with softmax at the end) - but every time i try to print `prediction` - i just get `<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x7fe0e8630c50>`

Is there any way I could get the actual results of the prediction? as in, the 0 or the 1 the network returns?! Thank you so much for reading.